# URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern when upload using spring

Tags: java, spring

I have only one starter in my porject :

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

2.1.6-RELEASE

I try to upload file and use `MultipartFile` but not working.
The framework works like `urlencoded form`

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/image", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<List<String>>> searchByImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(service.guess(file.getBytes())));
    }
```

and throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern
    at java.base/java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:225) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:142) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.FormHttpMessageReader.parseFormData(FormHttpMessageReader.java:146) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.FormHttpMessageReader.lambda$readMono$0(FormHttpMessageReader.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextStart$ContextStartSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextStart.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
```

the error happens:

```
    private MultiValueMap<String, String> parseFormData(Charset charset, String body) {
        String[] pairs = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(body, "&");
        MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>(pairs.length);
        try {
            for (String pair : pairs) {
                int idx = pair.indexOf('=');
                if (idx == -1) {
                    result.add(URLDecoder.decode(pair, charset.name()), null);
                }
                else {
                    String name = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx),  charset.name());
                    String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), charset.name());
                    result.add(name, value);
                }
            }
        }
```

I turn to use `FilePart` but get the same result...
Did I miss some configs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590080/java-urldecoder-throws-exception-when-used-with-a-string-containing-a

Comment: it doesn't help see my answer below @deshi

Answer (score 1):

It seems I set the header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in postman accidentally.
I removed it the result becomes :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-30T12:00:29.703+0000",
    "path": "/api/image",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present"
}
```

Seems it can't parse it.
After I put

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

into dependency.
It works fine.